# MapStruct cannot extract enum value from the object

Tags: java, kotlin, enums, mapstruct

I am trying to convert the Entity class to the DTO and mapstruct still complaining about copying the enum entry.

I have an `StatusOperationPriority` entity, which contains `Operation` constrain and Operation has one field `name`, which is a `ResourceOperation` enum entry. In the DTO, I want to have a list of the enum entries, so when mapping from the "sop.operation.name" to the enum, it does not work and I am getting "**ResourceOperation does not have an accessible constructor exception**".

```
@Entity
class StatusOperationPriority(

    ...
    
    val priority: Int,

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "operation_id", nullable = false)
    val operation: Operation,
)

@Entity
class Operation(

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    val name: ResourceOperation
)

class ResourceDto(
    ...
    val operations: List<ResourceOperation>,
)


// MapStruct interfaces

@Mapper(config = MapperConfiguration::class)
interface OperationMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "sop.operation.name", target = "resourceOperation")
    fun toResourceOperation(sop: StatusOperationPriority): ResourceOperation
    // This is just for only one entry, I am calling for each method in the list

}

@Mapper(config = MapperConfiguration::class, uses = [OperationMapper::class])
interface ResourceMapper {
    @Mappings(
        Mapping(source = "status.name", target = "status"),
    )
    fun toResourceDto(resource: Resource): ResourceDto
}
```

Do you know, if this is possible without using an expression in the @Mapping annotation?

Thanks a lot for your help.